# How to read pixel colors using SDL2?

Tags: image, sdl, sdl-2

I would like to load a png image, and get the color of some of it's pixels (in 32bit RGBA format). I've searched a lot, but haven't found a good working solution for this.

What I've found, is pixel manipulation using `SDL_LockTexture`. But don't want to change the image, just read some of its pixels.

Comment: Any particular reason why SDL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For you didn't specify that, I assume you are using [`SDL_image`](https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_image/docs/SDL_image.html) to load images. Therefore [`IMG_Load`](https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_image/docs/SDL_image.html#SEC11) is a good candidate of which to discuss.
As you can see from the link, it returns a [`SDL_Surface`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_Surface) (that you'll want probably to convert to a texture, but you don't need to do that to read its pixels).
With such an object you can use:

*[`SDL_LockSurface`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_LockSurface):

> Use this function to set up a surface for directly accessing the pixels.

*[`SDL_UnlockSurface`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_UnlockSurface):

> Use this function to release a surface after directly accessing the pixels.

The documentation states also that:

> Between calls to SDL_LockSurface() / SDL_UnlockSurface(), you can write to and read from surface->pixels, using the pixel format stored in surface->format.

Pixels and format are both at your disposal. It looks like a good candidate to do what you are asking for.

---

But...

> I would like to load a png image, [...]

Note that [`IMG_LoadPNG_RW`](https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_image/docs/SDL_image.html#SEC24) returns a `SDL_Surface` as well as `IMG_Load`.